# Detecting jailbroken device with webpage

Tags: ios, jailbreak

I'm designing a iPhone/iPad centered website. I would like to know if it's possible to detect if users are jailbroken/non jailbroken, does anyone know the tools required to achieve this?

Comment: do you got the solution? i would like to know the answer because i'm in the middle of doing this kind of webpage...

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that Safari is sandboxed well enough. No, you can't and even if you find a way to do so then someone could simply change the user agent to say they are on another mobile device.

Applications are sandboxed so you only have access to certain information which in most cases is what browser is your page running in and beyond that very little else except for information about the browser.

I'm curious as to why you would care if someones device is jailbroken or not on your website, and believe me if it mattered they would probably find a way around that to get access to your website even if you try your hardest to deny them access through a jailbroken device.

Comment: My website is directed towards jailbroken users, so users who're not jailbroken wont get to experience the full version of the website :p

Comment: Well I guess they will after all! You can always change the user agent with other desktop browser tools as well.